# How to update the angular version to 8 with the Ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have just setup the Ionic 4 project and with that Angular 7 version is there but I want to update the Angular 7 version to 8 and I am running the following cmd but showing the error.

**Commands That I am running to run:**

> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

**Error that is coming:**

> Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from
> "/home/Projects/myProjectName". Error: Could not find module
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/Projects/myProjectName".

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This:

**Commands That I am running to run to solve the problem:**

> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
>
> npm install --save-dev @ionic/angular-toolkit

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Any questions or comment on this?